# why is my model performing poorly for a keras sequential model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm a newbie to deep learning (and machine learning), and I created a python script that uses TensorFlow/Keras to identify flowers into different groups using [this dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/alxmamaev/flowers-recognition). Here is my code: (I'm doing this on Kaggle)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import Adam, SGD
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Dropout, Dense, Flatten
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import os

NUM_CLASSES = 5
IMG_SIZE = 150
DAISY = '../input/flowers-recognition/flowers/daisy'
DANDELION = '../input/flowers-recognition/flowers/dandelion'
ROSE = '../input/flowers-recognition/flowers/rose'
SUNFLOWER = '../input/flowers-recognition/flowers/sunflower'
TULIP = '../input/flowers-recognition/flowers/tulip'

x = []
y = []

def train_data_gen(DIR, ID):
    for img in os.listdir(DIR):
        try:
            path = DIR + '/' + img
            img = plt.imread(path)
            img = cv2.resize(img,(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))
            x.append(img)
            y.append(ID)
        except:
            None

train_data_gen(DAISY, 0)
train_data_gen(DANDELION, 1)
train_data_gen(ROSE, 2)
train_data_gen(SUNFLOWER, 3)
train_data_gen(TULIP, 4)

x = np.array(x)
y = to_categorical(y,num_classes = 5)

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.15)
x_train,x_val,y_train,y_val = train_test_split(x_train, y_train, test_size = 0.15)

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=False,
    samplewise_center=False,
    samplewise_std_normalization=False,
    rotation_range=60,
    zoom_range = 0.1,
    width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1,
    shear_range=0.1,
    fill_mode = "reflect"
)

datagen.fit(x_train)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=2, activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(x_train,y_train,batch_size=16), epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=x_train.shape[0]//16, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), verbose=1)
```

I know that the epochs is 10 here, but later on, I set it to 100. That was taking a really like time, so I stopped it on the 63rd epoch. Even then, it was floating around 60% accuracy, which is way too low. What could be something that I can change to make it more accurate? Would it be that my CNN is too small for this? Or is there something wrong with my data? I'm really new to this so I can't specify my question any further than "Why is my model performing badly?"
Thank you all in advance for the constructive feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You model uses too many Dropout layers. `model.add(Dropout(0.5))` effectively drops 50% of your neurons of your incoming layer and on top of that you have 4 of these. You are most probably **underfitting**.

After each `Conv2D` layer add a `keras.layers.MaxPooling2D` layer.

First try removing all the Dropout layers. In that case you will run the risk of overfitting - but if you don't overfit then there is no point of Dropout layers. If you do overfit, experiment with just 1 dropout layer with 20% dropout rate and gradually increase that to 50% and then maybe add another dropout of 20% and continue.